# header function dosn't work on server though work on localhost

Tags: header

[profile page](http://chatnpi.000webhostapp.com/profile.php) ,

[home or login page](http://chatnpi.000webhostapp.com/index.php),

[messages page](http://chatnpi.000webhostapp.com/messages.php),

[signup page](http://chatnpi.000webhostapp.com/signup.php),

the problem is when i search profile.php on the url bar it's show, but i gave a logic that if($login !== true){ header('Location: index.php')} but doesn't work it, and when does login with the roll and password doesn't redirect on the profile page, although it's work on localhost but not server.you can sign up and try to solve please help me any body

Answer (score 0):

This occur if you echoed something before header.

#### Let's check

To test this is the case enable error reporting: error_reporting(E_ALL); and set the errors to be displayed ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);.

You can fix this error by writing redirect logic to top of your file.

OR

You can use javascript to redirect.

```
<?php
if($user !== true){
echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
}
?>
```